# How to determine the partial derivative of a function, given its gradient evaluated at a point, and its composition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Assume that the function $f$ is $C^1$ and that $\nabla f(1, -4) = (3, -2)$. Consider the function: $h(x,y) = f(3y^2 - x, 2xy)$. What is $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(2, -1)$?

I've seen another question asking how to find $f$ given the symbolic gradient. But I haven't been able to find a question similar to mine (where the gradient evaluated at a point is given). My first guess is that **if** we were given the symbolic gradient we could integrate it w.r.t one variable (as seen in the previously mentioned question). Then we could apply the chain rule to find $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$. But I'm not sure how to approach this using only the gradient evaluated at a point. So I was hoping somebody could tell me how to approach this :)

EDIT:
So it seems I wasn't explicit enough in laying out my understanding of the question. So I'm aware that in order to evaluate $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(2, -1)$, we need to use the multivariable chain-rule. Let $u = 3y^2 - x$ and $v = 2xy$. Then we have:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
The partial derivatives are then:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 6y \quad \text{and} \quad  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2x
$$
Inserting into $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$ we get:

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}6y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} 2x
$$
But at this point I'm still not fully sure how to use the fact that $\nabla f(1, -4) = (3, -2)$ to determine $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$?

Answer (score 1):

We can write:

$$ F(x,y)= f \big(u(x,y) , v(x,y) \big) $$

Differentiating both sides with $y$ by the multivariable chain rule

$$ \frac{ \partial F}{\partial y}  = \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial u} \frac{d u}{ dy} + \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial v} \frac{ d v}{dy}$$

Observe that $$ ( \frac{ \partial f}{\partial u} , \frac{ \partial f}{\partial v})  = \nabla f|_{(u,v)}$$

Hence:

$$ \frac{ \partial F}{\partial y} = \nabla f|_{(u,v) }  \cdot ( \frac{du}{dy} , \frac{dv}{dy})$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I just made an update to my question, where I specifically lay out a bit more information on where I get lost - so would be helpful if you could elaborate on that thanks :)

Comment: Yeah basically the idea is that the chain rule is sort of like dot product between gradient and stuff put into inputs

Comment: Look at the expression carefully, you should be able to spot a 'vector function' dot proudct

Comment: Or better, write out the definition of gradient as a vector

Comment: So based on this, I wrote out: $(6y, 2x) \cdot \nabla f(1, -4)$. Evaluated at $(2, -1)$, we get $-6 \cdot 3 - 8 = -26$. But I'm not sure why we can just dot with $\nabla f$ evaluated at some arbitrary point?

Comment: it's a bit of notation abuse that you have done there, the f is being evaluated at (2,-1) but due to how it's input is ( interms of u,v) it seems it comes out that actually (1,-4) is being inputted

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $u=3y^2-x$, $v=2xy$ and $z=h(x,y)=f(u,v)$. Then, the chain rule is neatly:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$

Now, let us particularize everything at the given point $(x,y)=(2,-1)$. First of all, you have $(u,v)=(1,-4)$, so you can write the chain rule as:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right|_{(2,-1)}=\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right|_{(1,-4)} \left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{(2,-1)}+ \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right|_{(1,-4)} \left.\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right|_{(2,-1)}
$$

And you also have the information that $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right|_{(1,-4)}=3$, and $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right|_{(1,-4)}=-2$.

All that remains is to compute the partial derivatives of $u,v$ and substitute $(x,y)=(2,-1)$. Can you follow from here?

Comment: I just made an update to my question - would you mind elaborating on your answer according to the edits? :)

Comment: @VanTheMan I have included substituting at the points. Is it clearer now?